# Automatically add \maketitle for beamer class

Tags: beamer

The following code is intended to add `\maketitle` right after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{MYTITLE}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But this code raises an overfull `\vbox` warning and the navigation bar is located in a wrong place.

What happens???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [latexref.xyz](http://latexref.xyz/_005cAtBeginDocument.html):

> ```
> \AtBeginDocument{code}
> ```
>
> Save code and execute it when \begin{document} is executed, at the very end of the preamble. The code is executed after the font selection tables have been set up, so the normal font for the document is the current font. However, the code is executed as part of the preamble so you cannot do any typesetting with it.
>
> You can issue this command more than once; the successive code lines will be executed in the order that you gave them.

What you instead need is a hook which gets loaded after begin document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{MY TITLE}
\author{ME}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hello world}
  foobar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```